# After Migration to Spring Boot 3 my Project tries to download slf4j maven-metadata.xml from maven restlet

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, slf4j

On mvn compile, the app tries downloading from maven-restlet: https://maven.restlet.org/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/maven-metadata.xml

the transfer fails though with the following message: Could not transfer metadata org.slf4j:slf4j-api/maven-metadata.xml from/to maven-restlet (https://maven.restlet.org)

Does anyone know why this behaviour suddenly appears?

my pom:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>xxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
  <version>xxx</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>xxx</name>
  <description>xxx</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <!-- libs -->
    <testcontainers.version>1.17.6</testcontainers.version>
    <shedlock.version>5.1.0</shedlock.version>
    <!-- jacoco -->
    <jacoco.version>0.8.8</jacoco.version>

    <spring.security.version>6.0.1</spring.security.version>
    <azure.version>6.0.0-beta.3</azure.version>

    <!-- lts versions only-->
    <node.version>v16.17.1</node.version>

    <!-- validator-->
    <commons-validator.version>1.7</commons-validator.version>

    <!-- libs -->
    <sfdc.version>41.0</sfdc.version>
    <owasp.version>7.4.4</owasp.version>
    <resilience4j.version>1.7.1</resilience4j.version>

    <!-- please don't override spring boot's dependency management via an explicit dependency declaration -->
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.9.1</junit-jupiter.version>
    <selenide.version>6.11.0</selenide.version>
    <selenium.version>4.7.2</selenium.version>

    <!-- cdc -->
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    <spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin.version>4.0.0</spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin.version>

    <!-- monitoring and tracing -->
    <micrometer-tracing.version>1.0.0</micrometer-tracing.version>

    <!-- maven profile -->
    <skip.frontend.build>false</skip.frontend.build>
    <skip.frontend.webcomponent.build>true</skip.frontend.webcomponent.build>
    <skip.frontend.tests>false</skip.frontend.tests>
    <skip.backend.build>false</skip.backend.build>
    <skip.backend.tests.build>false</skip.backend.tests.build>
    <skip.backend.tests>false</skip.backend.tests>
    <skip.cdc.tests>false</skip.cdc.tests>
  </properties>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>allTests</id>
      <properties>
        <groups></groups>
      </properties>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>compileBE</id>
      <properties>
        <skip.frontend.build>true</skip.frontend.build>
        <skip.frontend.tests>true</skip.frontend.tests>
        <skip.backend.tests>true</skip.backend.tests>
        <skip.backend.tests.build>true</skip.backend.tests.build>
        <skip.cdc.tests>true</skip.cdc.tests>
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>compileFE</id>
      <properties>
        <skip.frontend.webcomponent.build>false</skip.frontend.webcomponent.build>
        <skip.frontend.tests>true</skip.frontend.tests>
        <skip.backend.build>true</skip.backend.build>
        <skip.backend.tests.build>true</skip.backend.tests.build>
        <skip.backend.tests>true</skip.backend.tests>
        <skip.cdc.tests>true</skip.cdc.tests>
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>compileBEAndFE</id>
      <properties>
        <skip.frontend.webcomponent.build>false</skip.frontend.webcomponent.build>
        <skip.frontend.tests>true</skip.frontend.tests>
        <skip.backend.tests>true</skip.backend.tests>
        <skip.backend.tests.build>true</skip.backend.tests.build>
        <skip.cdc.tests>true</skip.cdc.tests>
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>testFE</id>
      <properties>
        <skip.frontend.build>true</skip.frontend.build>
        <skip.backend.build>true</skip.backend.build>
        <skip.backend.tests.build>true</skip.backend.tests.build>
        <skip.backend.tests>true</skip.backend.tests>
        <skip.cdc.tests>true</skip.cdc.tests>
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>testBE</id>
      <properties>
        <excludeGroups>selenium</excludeGroups>
        <skip.frontend.build>true</skip.frontend.build>
        <skip.frontend.tests>true</skip.frontend.tests>
        <skip.backend.build>true</skip.backend.build>
        <skip.cdc.tests>true</skip.cdc.tests>
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>testUnit</id>
      <properties>
        <excludedGroups>integration, cdc, selenium, kafka</excludedGroups>
        <jacoco.execution.file>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-unit.exec</jacoco.execution.file>
        <skip.backend.build>true</skip.backend.build>
        <skip.frontend.build>true</skip.frontend.build>
        <skip.frontend.tests>true</skip.frontend.tests>
        <skip.cdc.tests>true</skip.cdc.tests>
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>cdcTests</id>
      <properties>
        <groups>cdc</groups>
        <jacoco.execution.file>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-cdc.exec</jacoco.execution.file>
        <skip.frontend.build>true</skip.frontend.build>
        <skip.frontend.tests>true</skip.frontend.tests>
        <skip.backend.build>true</skip.backend.build>
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>testSelenium</id>
      <properties>
        <groups>selenium</groups>
        <jacoco.execution.file>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-selenium.exec</jacoco.execution.file>
        <skip.backend.build>true</skip.backend.build>
        <skip.frontend.build>true</skip.frontend.build>
        <skip.frontend.tests>true</skip.frontend.tests>
        <skip.cdc.tests>true</skip.cdc.tests>
      </properties>
    </profile>


    <profile>
      <id>testIntegration</id>
      <properties>
        <groups>integration</groups>
        <jacoco.execution.file>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-integration.exec</jacoco.execution.file>
        <skip.backend.build>true</skip.backend.build>
        <skip.frontend.build>true</skip.frontend.build>
        <skip.frontend.tests>true</skip.frontend.tests>
        <skip.cdc.tests>true</skip.cdc.tests>
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>testIntegrationKafka</id>
      <properties>
        <groups>kafka</groups>
        <jacoco.execution.file>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-integration-kafka.exec</jacoco.execution.file>
        <skip.backend.build>true</skip.backend.build>
        <skip.frontend.build>true</skip.frontend.build>
        <skip.frontend.tests>true</skip.frontend.tests>
        <skip.cdc.tests>true</skip.cdc.tests>
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>COFA</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>

      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>copy</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>sfdc</groupId>
                  <artifactId>sfdc-canvas-sdk</artifactId>
                  <version>${sfdc.version}</version>
                  <type>jar</type>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
              <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/fits/lib</outputDirectory>
              <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>FITS</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>sfdc-canvas-sdk</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>install-file</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <file>${project.basedir}/fits/lib/sfdc-canvas-sdk-${sfdc.version}.jar</file>
                  <groupId>sfdc</groupId>
                  <artifactId>sfdc-canvas-sdk</artifactId>
                  <version>${sfdc.version}</version>
                  <packaging>jar</packaging>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>GITLAB-RUNNER</id>
      <properties>
        <failsafe.args>
          -Dtestcontainer.postgres.enabled=true
          -Dspring.datasource.use_datasource_proxy=true
          -Dspring.datasource.use_datasource_proxy_count_only=true
        </failsafe.args>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>DEV</id>
      <properties>
        <npm.profile>development</npm.profile>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- XML binding is optional since Java 10 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- starter for building web, REST applications. It uses tomcat server
      as default embedded server. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <!-- we're not using log4j, but this exclusion makes sure that it stays this way -->
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
      <artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
      <version>${shedlock.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
      <artifactId>shedlock-provider-jdbc-template</artifactId>
      <version>${shedlock.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Batch -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- UI -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Salesforce -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sfdc</groupId>
      <artifactId>sfdc-canvas-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>41.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Monitoring -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
      <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Messaging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Validator -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- TEST -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
      <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.yannbriancon</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-hibernate-query-utils</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
      <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
      <version>23.0.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    

    <!-- LOGGING -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
      <version>7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- TEST -->
    <!-- exclude junit 4 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
          <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUnit 5 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.tngtech.archunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>archunit-junit5</artifactId>
      <version>0.23.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.tngtech.archunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>archunit-junit5-engine</artifactId>
      <version>0.23.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testcontainers is tightly coupled with the JUnit 4.x rule API, this module provides an API that is based on the JUnit Jupiter extension model. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
      <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
      <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
      <version>5.12.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka</artifactId>
      <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
      <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
      <version>${selenide.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.idera.xray</groupId>
      <artifactId>xray-junit-extensions</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--Monitoring-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Schema migration -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
      <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- validation -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>31.1-jre</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
      <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.consumer</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit5</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.21</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>xerces</groupId>
          <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.consumer</groupId>
      <artifactId>java8</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.40</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>xerces</groupId>
          <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <!-- CDC -->
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${azure.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${micrometer-tracing.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Comment: please show your full pom file...

Comment: i had to remove the build tag. otherwise the file was too large.